# uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift

App keeps terminating/crashing due to tableView:numberOfRowsInSection unrecognized selector sent to instance when cell is clicked.

I've ensured that I have added the dataSource and delegate protocols to both my swift file and my TableView. I have also ensured that the swift file connected to the ViewController is the correct one. Whenever I select a cell in the TableView it crashes.

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return values.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let mainData = values[indexPath.row] as? [String:Any]

        cell.textLabel?.text = mainData?["listName"] as? String

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "selectList", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: The error shows `UIViewController`, nor your specific view controller class.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy for your response. Should I be looking somewhere else in my program?

Comment: You didn't set the correct classname for your view controller in the storyboard.

Comment: I see, it was because then view that my segue takes me to did not have a swift file attached to it yet. You comment did point me in the right direction - I appreciate your help!